# Logo and Home Icon

Tags: information-architecture

I have a site that is using a third party application to display content. On that application (also a site), the logo of my site is present. I'm trying to rearrange the information architecture so that if someone clicks a home icon, it will take them back to the home of the third party application (with my content on it), but clicking the logo will take them back to my site.

My dilemma: I'm afraid that users will confuse the home icon as the icon to take the user back to our site. Especially because both the logo and the home icon are on the same level. Although I don't want to put them on different levels because that takes up too much space. Should I just add text to the icon saying this application home or should I completely rethink how this is organized?

Comment: What exactly is the application?  If it's a store or something I would use the word 'Store'.  Ditto for forums.  Home should be the page they see if they type in your root URL.  Ditto for the logo I believe.

Comment: A screenshot would greatly improve the question here. Can you share an image @Majed? Please! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've actually have given the most accurate and correct answer to the question right in it :-)

As you mentioned, the logotypes are identical. I would recommend distinguish them with at least a little label telling user where will the link bring him. Unless the context is obvious, this will be always helpful information and prevent accidental and annoying actions.

Cheers,

Greg